# Locking for SQL Server concurrent accessing and modifying one record

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, locking

I have a table saving a list of completed jobs. Each job is done and inserted into that table after completion. There are multi-users who can fetch and run the same jobs. But before running the job should be checked (against the completed jobs table I've just mentioned) to ensure that it's not been run by anyone.

In fact the job is inserted into that table right before running the job, if the job is failed it will be removed from that table later. I have a stored procedure to check if a job exists in the table but I'm not really sure about the situation when multi-users can accidentally run the same jobs.

Here is the basic logic (for each user's app)

- check if job A has been existed in the completed jobs table:

  ```
  if exists(select * from CompletedJobs where JobId = JobA_Id)
       select 1
  else select 0
  ```
- if job A has been existed (actually being run or has been completed), the current user's action should stop here. Otherwise the current user can continue by first inserting job A into the completed jobs table:

  ```
  insert into CompletedJobs(...) values(...)
  ```

then it can just continue actually run the job and if it's failed, the Job A will be deleted from the table.

So in multi-threading, I can use `lock` to ensure that there is no other user's action involved between checking-inserting (kind of marking completion), so it should work safely. But in SQL Server I'm not so sure how that could be done. For example what if there are 2 users passing the step 1 (and both have the same result of `0` - meaning job is free to run)?

I guess both will then continue running the same job and that should be avoided. Unless at the phase of inserting the job (at the beginning of step 2), somehow I take benefit of unique constraint or primary key constraint to make SQL Server throw exception so that only one job can be continued successfully. But I feel that it's a bit hacky and not a nice solution. Are there some better (and more standard)  solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the primary/unique key approach is a valid one. But there are other options, for example you can try to lock the completed job row and if it success then run the job and insert it into the completed jobs table. You can lock the row even it doesn't exist yet.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @job_id int = 1
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 100
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    -- it will try to exclusively lock the row. If it success, the
    -- lock will be held during the transaction.
    -- If the row is locked, it will wait for 100 ms before failing
    -- with error 1222
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM completed_jobs WITH (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK, XLOCK) WHERE job_id = @job_id)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1
        COMMIT
        RETURN
    END
    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT -1
    -- execute the job and insert it into completed_jobs table
    SELECT 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
    SET LOCK_TIMEOUT -1
    -- 1222: Lock request time out period exceeded.
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1222 SELECT 2
    ELSE THROW
END CATCH
```

The script returns:

- `SELECT 0` if it completes the job
- `SELECT 1` if the job is already completed
- `SELECT 2` if the job is running by other one.

Two connections can run this script concurrently as long as `@job_id` is different.

If two connections run this script at the same time with the same `@job_id` and the job is not completed yet, one of them completes the job and the other one sees it as a completed job (SELECT 1) or as a running job (SELECT 2).

If one connection A executes `SELECT * FROM completed_jobs WHERE job_id = @job_id` while other connection B is executing this script with the same `@job_id`, then connection A will be blocked until B completes the script. It is true only if A runs under READ COMMITTED, REPEATABLE READ and SERIALIZABLE isolation level. If A runs under READ UNCOMMITTED, READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT or SNAPHOST, it won't be blocked, and it will see the job as uncompleted.

Comment: could I ask one more question about the Rowlock, for the query in your code, does that mean that it will lock only the row corresponding to `job_id` (if exists)? what will it lock if the row does not exist? In fact that kind of query may be run concurrently (for different job_ids), so locking should be affected only on a specific row (by job_id). Thank you!

Comment: if job_id is unique it will just lock one single row. Actually, SQL Server will lock the key, even though the row doesn't exist yet. This script can run concurrently as long as job_id is different. Readers running under READ COMMITTED,  REPEATABLE READ and SERIALIZABLE are also blocked when trying to read the row. However readers running under READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT and SNAPSHOT isolation levels are not blocked.

Comment: other readers execute the same checking query with `exists` as in your answer, I think that will be OK to lock others (I'm not so sure about default query hint)?

Comment: What do you mean by default query hint?

Comment: I mean about the default options SQL Server uses (without explicitly specified via `WITH`)

Comment: Ah, do you mean no hint at all. I have updated my answer, I hope It's more clear now.

Comment: actually what I'm not sure is about locking of this `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM completed_jobs WITH (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK, XLOCK) WHERE job_id = @job_id` when run by other users, because if it's not locked, some other client may continue if the result is `0`. BTW do I need to use `TRANSACTION` here? It looks like a way to release the lock? but I suppose the lock should be released automatically after the query `EXISTS ...` completed.

Comment: The lock is held during the transaction, when the transaction is over all locks are released. SQL Server always behaves that way, it only hold locks during a transaction. The hint HOLDLOCK causes SQL Server to hold the lock during the transaction, so the lock is not released until the transaction finishes.

Comment: I believe that some implicit transaction is used by SQL Server with the option `XLOCK` (and without using `HOLDLOCK`), that way the `EXISTS ...` should lock while running and release the lock after finished (so using explicit transaction is not necessary, unless we need to put other logic in one transaction while locking). I'll accept and upvote your answer in a few minutes, thank you very much.

Comment: implicit transactions are off by default. XLOCK doesn't turn it on. HOLDLOCK is needed because SQL SERVER releases the lock adquired by SELECT statements after executing them by default (under READ COMMITTED isolation level)